# Robocopy Mirror Backup gone awry

Tags: windows-7, command-line, backup, robocopy

I have created a simple batch file script for running Robocopy. It is set to make a backup of my user account folder to my external hard drive.

Here's the parameters for Robocopy:

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\Users\Finnly" "F:\Backups\Finnly (Backup)" /ZB /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /MIR /256 /MT:32 /XF ... /XD ... /R:3 /W:10 /V /TS /FP /ETA /LOG+:F:\Backups\Sync.log /TEE
```

For some reason when I run it, it backs up the files and then it seems to back them up again. The size of my **user account directory is 18.3 GB** but the **backup** of it **occupies over 30 GB**. After reading the contents of the log generated, it is obvious that it's **copying files more than once**. Why is this happening?

I'm running Windows Seven Home Premium 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suspect this is because Windows 7 has a lot of junction points for compatibility with older operating systems (eg My Music points to Music, My Pictures to Pictures etc).

If you add the /XJ switch, this will exclude the junction points. However that could mean that you are not backing up everything you think, especially if there is a junction point inside C:\Users\Finnly which points to somewhere outside that folder.

Comment: I modified the parameters to include the /XJ switch and it worked like a charm. The final size of the backup was 16.2 GB which is less than my actual user folder because I had excluded folders and files. I double-checked everything and I didn't miss any files or folders from junction points that are pointed outside the folder. Thanks for your help!